# how to set refresh after clicking on update,delete,insert button

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this code I want to update the `contact_no` field but it's not working, and also I want to set refresh after an update, delete or insert.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Update.
{
    if (TexBo_num.Text == ""  &&  TexBo_num.Text != "contact_no" )
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('contact number not be empty');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE detail SET name='" + TxtBox_name.Text + "',address='" + TexBo_add.Text + "',contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "' WHERE contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('record updated');", true);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more informations on the context. Looks like Windows Phone. Whats the value of TextBo_num?

Answer (score 0):

```
   contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "' WHERE contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "'"
```

This code does not make any sense. There's simply nothing to do with it. Read your query again. Please don't use dynamic sql like this. Use parameters to pass value.

To your refresh problem ,

In asp.net the click event always executes after the `page_Load` event. The simple workaround will be as shown below,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DisplayData();// The code that displays data from your database
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Update
{
 //Execute the click event Code;
 DisplayData();
}
```

To refresh a page you can simply write `Response.Redirect("Currentpage.aspx")` at the end of button click method.

Comment: actually in this code i am updating 2 fields..name and address but i also want to update the contact_no field which i am using for WHERE CLUSE...so how can i update contact_no field and i want to set refresh after all events...and this is in asp.net code backhand is C#...

Comment: The name and address will be set to your new value. But you are trying to set the same value to column `contact_no`. You are getting the same result for your query. You are using `TexBo_num.Text` to check where condition and to update the content.

Comment: exacly.....so if u knw then tell me how can i update the contact field value...and how can i refresh the page after all event...

Comment: Write the code that displays data in  your page into a new method ` DisplayData()` and call it as shown in the answer.

Comment: You read the query again. Its working well. You are asking to update the value to `TexBo_num.Text` where value is `TexBo_num.Text`. It does what it is!